# Access: Removing a duplicate if two fields are the same

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have an Access database table which sometimes contains duplicate ProfileIDs. I would like to create a query that excludes one (or more, if necessary) of the duplicate records.

The condition for a duplicate record to be excluded is: if the PriceBefore and PriceAfter fields are NOT equal, they are considered duplicate. If they are equal, the duplicate field remains.

[image]

In the example table above, the records with ID 7 and 8 have the same ProfileIDs. For ID 8, PriceBefore and PriceAfter are **not** equal, so this record should be excluded from the query. For ID 7, the two are equal, so it remains. Also note that PriceBefore and PriceAfter for ID 4 are the same, but as the ProfileID is not a duplicate, the record must remain.

What is the best way to do this? I am happy to use multiple queries if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a pointer query.  Call it pQuery:

```
SELECT ProfileID, Sum(1) as X
FROM MyTableName
HAVING Sum(1) > 1
```

This will give you the ProfileID of every record that's part of a dupe.

Next, find the records where prices don't match.  Call this pNoMatchQuery:

```
SELECT MyTableName.*
FROM MyTableName
INNER JOIN pQuery
ON pQuery.ProfileID = MyTableName.ProfileID
WHERE PriceBefore <> PriceAfter
```

You now have a query of every record that should be excluded from your dataset.  If you want to permanently delete all of these records, run a DELETE query where you inner join your source table to pNoMatchQuery:

```
Delete MyTableName.*
From MyTableName
Where Exists( Select 1 From pNoMatchQuery Where pNoMatchQuery.ID = MyTableName.ID ) = True
```

First, make absolutely sure that pQuery and pNoMatchQuery are returning what you expect before you delete anything from your source table, because once it's gone it's gone for good (unless you make a backup first, which I would highly suggest before you run that delete the first time).